# URL rewrite using .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have a URL `https://www.localhost/sitpoint/cellphone?id=Apple`
I want to convert `cellphone?id=Apple` into to `/Apple` like `https://www.localhost/sitpoint/Apple` using .htaccess url rewrite code.

Comment: Sounds great. Consider using mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to be able to know more about what you want to accomplish, you can't simply do it easily, and you have to consider a lot of other factors, but here is a code you can use to let Apache know that whatever goes inside the first URL parameter, goes as a value for a variable::

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

In your index.php file: **(or any other file you're redirecting to)**

```
if(isset($_GET["id"])) {

        //Split URL by '/' character, putting each one inside an array
        $_URL = explode("/", filter_var(rtrim($_GET["id"], "/"), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

        $id = $_URL[0];

        //if user inputs www.myaapp.com/Apple
        //$id would be = 'Apple'

    }
```